# Excel JavaScript API requirement set 1.8 events

Tags: excel, office-js

New event features planned for requirement set 1.8 of the Excel JavasScript API are listed in the [ExcelApi OpenSepc](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/Event_README.md) site.

Will the events `tableDataChangedEvent` and `worksheetDataChangedEvent` fire under the following conditions:

- The user hides/unhides rows.
- Rows are hidden/unhidden as a result of applying a filter.
- When cells containing formulas change values due to modifications in another worksheet.

Comment: It may be better to ask this question to the devs on that project. There are two people listed at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming data change event in Worksheet will be fired when data is actually changed. Apply this criteria to cells:

1. The user hides/unhides rows -> No firing. Since the data weren't changed.
2. Rows are hidden/unhidden as a result of applying a filter.-> No firing. Since the data weren't changed.
3. When cells containing formulas change values due to modifications in another worksheet.-> No firing. Since the data weren't changed. In this case, cell treats the formula as its data, rather than the outcome of the formula. In addition, we are developing another events called **Calculate Events**, which would be fired when the dependencies of formula are changed and caused the outcome changing.

Any feedback on DataChange/Calculate events designing are welcome :)